# RequireJS, require method argument is null

Tags: requirejs

Im new to RequireJS framework and I'm having an annoying error.
I have a file custom.js that define a module:

```
define(function () {
    return
    ({
        hello: function()
        {
            alert('hello');
        }
    });
});
```

and in my script tag in an ASP.NET MVC view I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            require(['custom'], function (data) {
                data.hello();
            });
</script>
```

Why i'm having data argument null? Should not be the object returned by the module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known curse of Javascript: since the `;` ending a statement is optional, the JS engine sees the `return` statement in a line and...returns. It disregards any code following it.

Just do (note only newline changes + the removal of unneeded parentheses):

```
define(function () {
    return {
        hello: function() {
            alert('hello');
        }
    };
});
```